# Why im getting NullPointerException in this specific case?

Tags: java, pointers, exception, matrix, null

I don't know why im getting a NPE while consulting if a position of a 2darray of objects (cells) is empty or not. Im checking this by `if ((matrix[i][j]) == null)`   and i've tried  `if ((matrix[i][j]) != null)` but im getting the NPE again and again. I want to know how i check it without that NPE...

```
public class 2darrayofcells {

//rows and columns are final by requirement 
private final int rows;
private final int colums;
private Cell[][] matrix;
//the array needs an initial object
private Cell initialCell;

//Position class consist on 2 integers (x,y)

public 2darrayofcell(Position pos){
    //the arg pos is used to create the initial cell in the specified position of the array
    rows = 10;
    columns = 10;
    matrix = new Cell[rows][columns];
    initialCell = new Cell();
    matrix[pos.getX()][pos.getY()] = initialCell;

}

. . .

//Here i put a cell in a position of the array but before putting it 
//i need to know if it's empty. It will return true if the cell is added to 
//that position 
public boolean putCell(Cell cell, Position pos){

    //Null Pointer Exception
    if (matrix[pos.getX()][pos.getY()] == null) {

        //Do stuff
        return true;
    } 
  return false;
}

}
```

The main class...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Position pos = new Position(5,5);
    2darrayofcells test = new 2darrayofcells(pos);
    //test only has an object in 5,5
    //The position for the cell i want to insert (3,3) is empty
    Position cellPos = new Position(3,3);
    Cell testCell = new Cell();
    test.putCell(testCell, cellpos);


}
```

The matrix got its initialization...

Comment: are you able to compile your code? Whats the definition of Cell/Position class?

Comment: are you able to compile the code as I dont think Java allows class names to start with numeric character which conflicts with 2darrayofcells class name and also your constructor (public 2darrayofcell(Position pos)) has invalid signature, maybe you missed a 's' in the end of name.

Comment: @almasshaikh The code compiles, the problem came when trying the funcionalities. Cell contains 2 ints.

Comment: @Himanshu I know but that's not the real name of the class. It's an example name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possible explanations for a NPE on this line:

```
    if (matrix[pos.getX()][pos.getY()] == null) {
```

Explanation #1: `matrix` is `null`.

Explanation #2: `pos` is `null`.

Explanation #3: `matrix[pos.getX()]` is `null`.

---

It is not possible top work out which of those explanations is the correct one.  Basically, the snippets of code are inconsistent (i.e. they wont compile) and the inconsistencies make it infeasible to figure out what happens in your real code.

Even ignoring the compilation errors, different parts of the code seem to imply that none of the explanations is correct.  However that **cannot be true**.  If precisely the line above throws an NPE then there are no other possible explanations than the three above.  None.

Comment: It's strange. The matrix has all of its elements created by default (null). The matrix exists...

Comment: I can't help you.  The code in your question is clearly not the real code.  Unless you post an SSCCE, I can give you no further help.

Comment: Anyway, thanks. I'll read again my code, maybe i didn't see any issue related with one of that three explanations.

Comment: As you said, i was passing to putCell() a null position as 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to putCell(), don't you want to pass cellPos as a second argument?

Comment: Yes, i forget to write it. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Cell looks like, but you probably try to use getter on cells with null as default value:

```
if (matrix[pos.getX()][pos.getY()] == null)
pos.getX() throws NullPointerException
```

Try:

```
if (matrix[0][0] == null) {
```

Does it work ?

Comment: No... I don't know even if it is necessary to throw the exception to work